# how to read value from awk command?

Tags: linux, awk, environment-variables

I have result file where I need to read the value of "rx cells " the report file is as given as below: 
Content of test.log file is as follows:

```
    co_result=test.log  

    ZyXEL IES-1000> statistics port 12 0 33
    [adsl channel 12-0/33]
    tx packets: 56
    rx packets: 60
    tx rate   : 0
    rx rate   : 0
    tx cells  : 468
    rx cells  : 1707
    errors    : 0
    ZyXEL IES-1000>
```

I am using the following command to read the rx cells value:

```
    cells=$(grep -e 'cells' $co_result | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{print $1}'| awk 'NR%2{printf $0"";next;}1')
    echo "Var_value: $cells"
```

but when I tried to run the above 2 commands in a file. I am getting following output , where the first few characters in echo is not displaying:

```
       1707value: 530
```

I am expecting only 1707 in $cells variable but it prints wrongly. I am not understanding the issue . Could you please help to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command substitution is unnecessarily complex.

Instead:

```
cells=$( awk '/rx cells/ { print $NF }' <"$co_result" )
printf 'Var_value: %s\n' "$cells"
```

`$NF` will be the last whitespace-delimited field on the line, and this is printed if the line contains the string `rx cells`.

Also make sure that the input file is a Unix text file and not a DOS text file.  Run `dos2unix` on the file to convert it to a Unix text file.

---

Looking at your command:

```
grep -e 'cells' $co_result | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{print $1}'| awk 'NR%2{printf $0"";next;}1'
```

First: `grep -e 'cells' $co_result` would fail if `$co_result` contained a space or tab or newline, or any other special character (since it's unquoted).

The command outputs

```
tx cells  : 468
rx cells  : 1707
```

Then: `cut -d: -f2`.  This outputs

```
 468
 1707
```

Then: `awk '{print $1}'`. This outputs the same as above, but with the initial spaces removed

Then: `awk  'NR%2{printf $0"";next;}1'`. This is an obfuscated way of doing `paste -d' ' - -` and outputs

```
468 1707
```

The `echo` later will output

```
Var_value: 468 1707
```

The reason you don't get that is that your input file is a DOS text file and contains carriage returns at the end of each line.  Therefore, the cursor jumps back to the start of the line after printing `468`.

Use `dos2unix` on you input file.

Where you get `530` from, I don't know.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. I tried simple grep command instead of awk as of now

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use `grep`:

```
 cells=$(grep -F "rx cells" "$co_result" | grep -oE "[0-9]+")
```

this would extract the number into your variable by:

`grep -F "rx cells" $co_result`: this is extracting the line that contains `rx cells  : 1707`
`grep -oE "[0-9]+"`: only output the match of the regexp that matchs only number: 1707

You could also use the more elequant `sed` group substitution to extract the value like this:

```
cells=$(sed  -r -n 's/rx cells.*\W([0-9]+)/\1/p' "$co_result")
```

- `-r`: enable extended regex
- `-n`: only print explicit line
- 's///p': s for substitute, p to explicitly print the line that match the pattern.
- `rx cells.*\W([0-9]+)` match `rx cells` `.*\W` matches any character until a Non-word character and ([0-9]+) capture in group one or more digits.
- `\1` replace output by group one which contains n captured digits.

Comment: Thank you looks simple I tried the same thing with 2 stages.

Comment: but after getting the number 1707 , I am trying to compare it with other value max_pcr=100, its says max_pcr is not not number ..                                                              
               if [ $cells < $max_pcr ]; then
                     echo " Co_result pass: $cells"  else echo "Co_result fail"    where the number max_pcr is not considered ..

Comment: @NageshHS Well I think the official syntax is `if [ "$cells" -gt "$max_pcr" ] then` but that's out of the scope of your initial question

Comment: Thank u, I have fixed the other comparison issue , anyway thanks for your inputs on actual issue.